# SwiftUI - Element-wise multiplication of arrays

Tags: arrays, swiftui, multiplication

Why doesn't this code work for element-wise multiplication of two linear arrays?

I've tried other similar setups but get the error:

> Binary operator '*' can not be applied to two 'Any' operators.

What is an 'Any' operator?

The app itself is to generate multiplication questions so that you have to tap the correct answer

```
@State var mult1 = [...]
@State var mult2 = [...]

    var ans : [Int] {
        var answers: [Int] = []

        for num in 0 ..< mult1.count {
            answers.append(mult1[num] * mult2[num])
        }
        return answers
    }
```

Where mult1 and 2 are calculated within a button as such:

```
let ranges = generateQs(upTo: upTo, numQs: numQuestions)
mult1 = ranges.range1
mult2 = ranges.range2
```

And

```
func generateQs(upTo: Int, numQs: Int) -> (range1:[Int], range2:[Int]) {
        var range1: [Int] = []
        var range2: [Int] = []
        var nums: String = ""
        var usedNums: [String] = []
        
        while range1.count < numQs{
            let num1: Int = (Array(1...upTo).shuffled()[1])
            let num2: Int = (Array(1...upTo).shuffled()[1])
            //Generate 2 random numbers in Upto Range

            if num1 <= num2 {
                nums = makeString(small: num1, big: num2)
            }
            else if num1 > num2 {
                nums = makeString(small: num2, big: num1)
            }
            
            //Check if nums are already used
            if isOriginal(nums: nums, usedNums: usedNums) {
                usedNums.append(nums)
                range1.append(num1)
                range2.append(num2)
            }
        }
        return(range1,range2)
    }
    
    func makeString(small: Int, big: Int) -> String {
        let smaller = String(small)
        let larger = String(big)
        
        let combined = smaller + larger
        return combined
    }
    
    func isOriginal(nums: String, usedNums: [String]) -> Bool {
        !usedNums.contains(nums)
    }
```

Where upTo is an integer from 1 to 12
and numQs is an integer from 1 to 20

How do I turn these mult1 & 2 arrays into a form I can work with?

Comment: Would you show complete reproducible code?

Comment: There you go! Sorry, I didn't realise it was the mult1 and mult2 variables that were messed up

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error with your provided code. How do you declare and initialize the vars `mult1` and `mult2`? `@State var mult1 = [...]` is certainly a placeholder for something.

Comment: Thanks, I had not declared the arrays as [Int]. I assumed that by initialising them as an empty array mult = [] it would infer the type. Thanks again!